# How do I compute uncertainties in the positions transformed using Helmert transformation?

Tags: python, gps, coordinate-system, matlab, mathematics

I am familiar with Python, MATLAB and Mathematica. My data is given by Cartesian coordinates (positions in X,Y,Z (meters), standard deviations XX, YY, ZZ (meters) and a correlation matrix (XY, YZ, ZX).

For the Helmert transformation I will probably use Geodetic toolbox in MATLAB.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you may be better suited to one of the other Stack Exchanges. There's are a few maths ones.